# Which technique is used to create high value resistance inside a IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, vlsi

Various ICs have resistances inside them. For example, AVR microcontrollers have an internal 10k pull-up resistor inside them. Which kind of technique is used to design these resistors? If I want to design a resistor of 470k or 100k, which procedure I should follow?

Comment: If accuracy isn't required they often use FETs as resistors inside IC's because this uses much less silicon space.

Comment: It also depends on the semiconductor technology that you are using. The PDK should provide some options for implementing resistors e.g. with polysilicon.

Comment: Do you mean voltage-controlled resistor? @Unimportant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first step will be to determine what type of resistors are available in the process technology you're using.

Common resistor types are:

- Nwell resistors
- diffusion resistors (P-type or N-type)
- polysilicon resistors

If you want high value resistors you need to keep the area that will be needed for the resistors in check.

Usually the poly resistors offer the highest resistance for a given area.

The poly resistors are normally made of the polysilicon that is also used to form the gates of NMOS and PMOS transistors.

For transistors we typically want a **low** resistance, that would be a resistance of for example 300 ohms / square.

Some processes offer an "high poly" resistance option where the square resistance is higher, for example 1 kohm / square.

Since you don't want one very long and thin resistor you generally need to make many smaller resistors, of for example 20 kohms and connect many of these in series.

Realize that resistor values aren't very well controlled. A tolerance of +/- 20% is quite common. Also very narrow resistors (small Width) can have larger variations (and mismatch) than wider resistors. But making a resistor wider while keeping the total resistance the same will result in a larger used area so there's an area versus accuracy trade-off.

It is suggested in the comments that a FET can be used as a resistor. Yes it can but its value will depend on the applied voltage so this can only be used in certain applications.

As an alternative for pull-up / pull-down resistors which need to have a high value but also a small area, I would also consider using a MOSFET as a current source. That current source would then be designed for a very small current, for example 1 uA. Part of such a current mirror can be shared with many inputs making the total area much smaller compared to using high value resistors.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Does it imply anything about the resistor construction when an IC (such as an instrumentation amplifier, or a digital potentiometer, for instance) has laser-trimmed internal resistors? I would imagine not every method of creating transistors on a die is amenable to trimming.

Comment: @Hearth Laser trimming is an extremely expensive option so I would only expect that in the highest of high-end ICs. Realize that although absolute values on an IC are inaccurate, matching can be very good . An instrumentation amp. needs matched resistors so that can usually be done quite well. Also trimming is an option but that's trimming by using switches (just MOSFETs, a MOSFET costs nothing on an IC) so we can make trimmable resistors using MOS switches and some control logic if needed...

Comment: ...Also we can make large MOSFETs using multiple small ones in parallel and then switch on/off some of those for trimming purposes. Making a current mirror with a programmable output current (like an ADC) is quite simple actually and used wherever there is a need for that. Digital potmeter: just many switches with resistors. No trimming needed I would think as you could just make a finer resolution by using more switches (for example a 10 bit potmeter that's actually 12 bit so some trimming can be done).

Comment: Oh definitely, I'm talking about the highest of high-end instrumentation amplifiers--I doubt your average $2 inamp is going to have laser-trimmed matching. But a $20 one from AD with really tight specs may. I made a guess that they might laser-trim some digital pots, but I don't actually know of any application where that would be worth it, on second thought.